# After downloading a Symfony aplication which command(s) do I have to execute in order to configure the database?

Tags: symfony1

Let's say I want to download a Symfony's complete app, for instance, [Jobbet](http://svn.jobeet.org/doctrine/tags/release_day_24/)

I'll have everything necessary to run the app in my desktop but it wouldn't really work with an empty database. Is there a terminal command to create and fill the database with everything that the app requires?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, configure your database, either by command line, or editing the "/config/databases.yml" file.

```
> php symfony configure:database "mysql:host=YOURHOST;dbname=YOURDBNAME" YOURDBUSER YOURDBPASS
```

Next, if you want to generate everything, forms, filters, models and data, run the following command:

For Doctrine ORM:

> php symfony doctrine:build --all --and-load

For Propel ORM:

> php symfony propel:build --all --and-load

This should get you up and running.  You should definitely look at the tutorial for Jobeet posted on the Symfony Project website for more information on how this project works:

Doctrine:  http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/

Propel:  http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Propel/en/

Answer (score 1):

You can either edit *config/databases.yml* file or use configure:database task. For more info run:

```
./symfony help configure:database
```

Comment: After that, he also needs to build the models/forms/filters, create the tables and insert any fixtures. To do that, execute `php symfony propel:build-all-load` or it's doctrine equivalent.